# Google ADS View repeat request

Tags: swift, dictionary, uikit, google-ads-api

I am using google banner ads in swift application and I used the cache method and the viewForHeaderInSection method to ensure that the banners you use make a single request. but when scrolling on the page, without seeing the header View, google requests directly and when I hover over it, it sends a request again. how do i fix a single request

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    for item in sectionItems {
        switch item {
        case let .BannerSectionItem(item, modelData):
            if let cache = adCellDict[section] {
                return cache
            } else {
                let adView = BannerCellView.loadFromNib()
                adView.configureAd(rootVC: self, item: item, model: modelData)
                adCellDict[section] = adView
                return adView
            }
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

i treid every method